# Excel row filtering so that only cells with duplicate entries show

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large data set.

I want to filter my data so that the column that I am filtering only shows a cell (and the relevant row) if the cell contents are the same as at least one other cell in the column.

I don't know how to add excel sample data here.

The reason for this (if it helps to visualize what I am trying to do) - is that most of the rows are unique, and then a few rows of data contain cell contents which appear many times.

If I can filter out the unique rows, then this would leave only rows of data which are useful.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried just simple filtering. I have tried to select the cell contents which I know appear in more than one cell, but there is just too many individual entries (around 12,000). I have about 20,000 rows of data. 12,000 or so would have unique contents in this column. the remaining 8,000 would consist of about 100 different entries (averaging about 80 of each). It is these 8,000 rows that are useful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do so by adding a new column :

The idea :  a new cell that counts the number of times the content of the cell appears in the column.

let's say the cells you want to select are in column A, your new column should contain (lets assume it's in column F)

formula of F2 :

```
=countif(A:A,"="&A2)
```

Extend this formula to all your table.

Each of the cells in your F column should now contain the number of times the specific value in A is repeated.

Just filter by column F, keeping all the values >= 2 (all values that repeat themselves)